# Which is correct: Is or has?

Tags: grammaticality, past-participles

Which of these sentences is correct?

1. The drug **is** worn off.
2. The drug **has** worn off.

Or are they both correct?

If I added the word *Now* at the beginning of the sentence, would the correct answer remain *has*?

3. **Now** the drug **has** worn off.

I would assume the answer would be the same with or without *now*.

Comment: The drug is not **equivalent** to its dissipation, so ***is** worn off* is wrong. *has worn off* is correct.

Comment: If you were Shakespeare, _is_ would probably be your auxiliary of choice. In this millennium, however, the rather broad and ill-defined category of ‘motion verbs’ has generally switched to using the same auxiliary as all the other verbs, and _has_ is the only reasonable option.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Most but not quite all of the [is now worn off](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22is%20now%20worn%20off%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en#q=%22is+now+worn+off%22&lr=lang_en&tbs=lr:lang_1en&tbm=bks&start=0) instances are indeed from the 18th and 19th centuries, not the 20th or the 21st. However, a few do linger.